# Would a brake caliper cover work here, little clearance?

Tags: brakes, brake-calipers, aftermarket-upgrade

I just got a very low mileage Lexus IS350 convertible. About the only thing on the car that looks old is the brakes.

I was thinking to get some after-market caliper covers.

The rear has plenty of clearance. But notice on the front ones, I can hardly get my finger between the wheel and the calipers.

Is it normal or possible to add caliper covers, when there is this little clearance?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't think there's a definitive answer here as you have not supplied any measurements of the gap or the covers you would use. It looks too tight to me, but that's totally subjective. I would suggest you paint them instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A caliper cover should fit without issue. Reason I say this is, because the covers are made of thin material and are designed to fit there. They are probably 1/4 (or less) the thickness of your finger.

Personally (and this is strictly my opinion), I think the covers are kind of tacky. They don't look very good. I agree with GdD (in comments). Painting them would be a good alternative. Paint, even done right, won't last but a couple of years. An even better alternative would be to get them powder coated with the color of your choice. Powder coating is very durable and comes in many different colors/styles. You have to have your calipers rebuilt in the process of getting it done (seals have to be removed and cannot be reused), however the outcome of getting it done is usually very good.

Comment: Another option might be to get some upgraded and fancy looking replacement calipers.  Having the existing ones prepared, powder-coated, rebuilt, and re-installed might be more expensive than just installing some new ones that you like the way they look.

Comment: @jwh20 - Nothing wrong with that if you can find the specific ones which fit your car as well as done as you want them. Someone with a bit mechanical knowhow can easily take a brake caliper apart and prep it for coating. Rebuild kits are relatively cheap.

Comment: Paulster, that's excellent info and will help anyone googling here. You know, i actually agree with you, I'm not getting covers for it!  It's just the wrong type of vehicle.  And yeah it would look fine with brand new "brembos" all around but again it just doesn't strike me as a "project car" you know!  I'm thinking just simply replace them with new ie same original parts you know, may make it look fresh.

Comment: thanks all !!!!

Comment: @Fattie - I think that's an awesome choice.

Comment: indeed, it just occurs to me, they can't have looked "that bad" when brand new from the showroom heh!